# Core Data destructive migration

Tags: swiftui, core-data, core-data-migration

I have this little nagging problem where I need to define migration each time let say I add new column. I get data from API and do not mind destroying everything and rebuilding. Android Room have what we call destructive migration where Room destroys everything and recreates empty version of new schema.

Is there such instruction for core data, where I can tell it: If versions mismatches, destroy everything and create empty database using latest schema?

Comment: You could juste delete your current database (ie: remove the file at storeURL), that way it doesn't have to migrate.

Comment: In development that is easy. I just delete the app. But how do I do that in user device which I have no control?

Comment: Don't delete the app, delete the database file. When launching your new version, use a boolean to know if you've done the operation yet, and delete the database file. In CoreData, you have a `storeURL` set somewhere, delete the file there. It should do the trick.

Comment: Seem like the way to go. Can you point me toan example or documnentation? Never thought that was possible!